# I can sing and not be singing

Tags: grammar

I can sing along to a love songs and not be singing them to him.

If separated into two sentences, how is the second one like? 
I cannot be singing them to him?

Instead of using "be singing" can this go like this too - and not sing them to him?

Comment: The meaning of your original sentence isn't clear. Do you mean to use grammar such as "I can ride my bicycle without using my hands."?

Comment: I can sing along to love songs, but i cannot or don't sing them solo to him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence isn't clear. Nor is it grammatical.

Maybe be you want to say:

I can sing along to love songs, but I cannot sing them solo/alone to him or I don't sing them alone/solo to him.